# Script to build the LAST commit in a Gerrit topic branch

Tags: gerrit

We're using Gerrit.  We thought we could do the following:

1. create some commits on a topic branch:
        - a
        - b
        - c
2. Push those commits to gerrit.
3. Get some reviews.
4. Have Jenkins build only the last commit of the bunch.

Unfortunately, it looks like gerrit internally creates three different branches for those three commits, and when we have Jenkins run the script to build the topic,  it winds up picking a different commit than the one we intended.  Is there someway to get the behavior we desire?

Comment: Does the Jenkins job run before or after submit? Which commit does it pick, a, b or c?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the project configuration to only create one review for your series of changes. This can be done by setting the **Create a new change for every commit not in the target branch** to false

Biggest disadvantage is that you can't review what has been changed in the changesets leading up to the latest change.

See the [Gerrit Documentation](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.14.5.1/project-configuration.html#_use_target_branch_when_determining_new_changes_to_open)

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit always creates one change (review) for each commit pushed. There's no way to create one unique change for a bunch of commits. Commits are stored in special branches (like, for example, refs/changes/12/40312/1) until they aren't submitted (merged in the final branch).

You can, of course, build several commits at once after they are submitted to the branch but you only can trigger Jenkins to start a build every time some commit is merged in the branch (one build for each commit). If you want to have just one build for a bunch of commits you could consider to make scheduled builds started automatically some time of the day (night builds).